# Continuous Queries are not running

Tags: influxdb

I use Influxdb v0.11 in my project.
I have next retention policies:

```
name        duration    replicaN    default
default     0           1           false
two_days    48h0m0s     1           true
eight_days  192h0m0s    1           false
```

Also I have this continuous query:

```
name: mydb
-----------------
name                    query
mean_for_1h_watcher_6   CREATE CONTINUOUS QUERY mean_for_1h_watcher_6 ON mydb BEGIN SELECT mean(respond_time) AS respond_time INTO mydb.eight_days.week_respond_time_watcher_6 FROM mydb.two_days.day_respond_time_watcher_6 WHERE time > now() - 5s GROUP BY time(5s) END
```

When I fill my `mydb.two_days.day_respond_time_watcher_6` measurement with data every second continuous query is not running. There is no new points in my `mydb.eight_days.week_respond_time_watcher_6` and no records in log file. But when I execute `select` statement from this continuous query manually, new points appears in measurement.
This problem presents in Influxdb v0.10 and v0.11.

So, any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug.

There are two issues [1](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/5896) & [2](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/6096) related to this.

There should be another `0.11.x` release where they are fixed soon.